# String cannot be cast to org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot

While using the following code, I'm getting a `ClassCastException: String
cannot be cast to org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity`.

```
@Autowired
private  ClientService clientService;

public void methodA() {
    String url = ...
    ResponseEntity<String> resEntity = clientService.callService(url);
}
```

Comment: clientService.callService(url); is returning String ? which would cause error while assigning it to ResponseEntity. Whats the return type of callService method?

Comment: ResponseEntity.ok(clientService.callService(url));

Answer (score 0):

The error means:

this statement

```
clientService.callService(url);
```

is calling the method callService which is returning an object of the class String, that is not the same type to ResponseEntity there so this is invalid:

```
ResponseEntity resEntity = clientService.callService(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Plese send the whole stacktrace to be sure of previous answers.

People here are probably right, but it seems strange that an IDE doesn't tell you that the return type of `clientService.callService(url)` is incompatible with the type of your variable...